# Error related to pkg-config when installing frei0r as part of another package

Tags: macos, homebrew, make, build

I am trying to build https://github.com/mltframework/shotcut on OS X Lion (using their script in `scripts/build_shotcut.sh`) and after numerous hurdles I'm stuck on this error:

```
./configure: line 16062: syntax error near unexpected token `OPENCV,'
./configure: line 16062: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(OPENCV, opencv >= 1.0.0, HAVE_OPENCV=true, true)'
ERROR: Unable to configure frei0r
```

From [what I already Googled](http://myitcorner.com/blog/?p=207) this means that the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro hasn't been defined, which probably means there's something wrong with my `pkg-config`, which I installed via Homebrew. Sounds like the `pkg.m4` file isn't found.

When I `brew install pkg-config` I get the following warning:

```
Warning: m4 macros were installed to "share/aclocal".
Homebrew does not append "/usr/local/share/aclocal"
to "/usr/share/aclocal/dirlist". If an autoconf script you use
requires these m4 macros, you'll need to add this path manually.
```

Well I've appended that line to the dirlist file and it doesn't fix the problem above.

**Can anyone suggest a way forward here?**

I have briefly tried building my own `pkg-config` from source but (bizarrely) when I tried to `./configure` I got the following error:

```
checking for pkg-config... no
./configure: line 13540: --exists: command not found
configure: error: pkg-config and glib-2.0 not found, please set GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to the correct values
```

If building pkg-config needs pkg-config it seems like a weird catch 22 situation... I think this is probably an unnecessary sidetrack anyway.

Comment: I'd still kind of like to be able to build this from source myself, but for anyone else who just wants to have a look at Shotcut there are binaries (not very visible to Google) here: http://www.shotcut.org/bin/view/Sandbox/TestLatest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug in pkg-config 0.26, not so good solution is use 0.25:

http://manulix.wikidot.com/build-howto#toc26